# Split file with multiple delimited entries in some columns into separate lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have a very large file with the following basic format, with a number of additional fields:

```
 posA,id1,id2,posB,id3,name,(n additional fields)
 1,ENST7,ENSP93,1,ENSG92,Gene1
 2,ENST25;ENST76;ENST35,ENSP91;ENSP77;ENSP78,515;544;544,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST25;ENST76;ENST35,ENSP91;ENSP77;ENSP78,515;544;544,ENSG765,Gene2
 4,ENST54;ENST93,ENSP83;ENSP36,1864;722,ENSG48,Gene3
 5,ENST54;ENST93,ENSP83;ENSP36,1864;722,ENSG48,Gene3
 6,ENST54;ENST93,ENSP83;ENSP36,1864;722,ENSG48,Gene3
```

Line one (posA=1) has a single entry for each column, and does not need to be modified. For lines with a variable number of multiple entries for some columns, for the third line (posA=2), the first entry for "id1" (ENST25) is paired with the first entry for "id2" (ENSP91) and the first entry for "posB" (515), and so on, but the columns with a single entry (eg, "posA", "id3", "name") apply to all of the paired entries in columns 2-4. Some fields in addition to columns 2-4 also rarely contain multiple entries.

I want to split the columns with multiple entries into separate lines, while retaining the data from the other columns, like so:

```
 posA,id1,id2,posB,id3,name,(n additional fields)
 1,ENST7,ENSP93,1,ENSG92,Gene1
 2,ENST25,ENSP91,515,ENSG765,Gene2
 2,ENST76,ENSP77,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 2,ENST35,ENSP78,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST25,ENSP91,515,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST76,ENSP77,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST35,ENSP78,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 4,ENST54,ENSP83,1864,ENSG48,Gene3
 4,ENST93,ENSP36,722,ENSG48,Gene3
 ...
```

What is the best approach for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to explain more about the pairing. Please give more sample input. To me, the existing explanation and the single example are not enough to understand the syntax. I spotted the `;` instead of `,` but I would have expected splitting into `2,c,+` and `2,d,e,f,+`. Also please state the language you are using and show your own coding attempts, in order to avoid the impression of just looking for a free coding service. Taking the [tour] is highly recommended and you definitly should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example as an example that at most there will be two-compound attributes, then using simple *parameter expansion with substring removal*, you can accomplish what you intend fairly easily, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r p a1 a2 a3; do 
    [[ $a1 =~ ';' ]] && { 
        printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$p" "${a1%;*}" "${a2%;*}" "$a3"
        printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$p" "${a1#*;}" "${a2#*;}" "$a3"
    } || printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$p" "$a1" "$a2" "$a3"
done < "$1"
```

Where `[[ $a1 =~ ';' ]]` checks for a `';'` in `$a1` and if found then picks off the first attribute in `$a1` and `$a2` with `${a1%;*}` and `${a2%;*}`. Then for the second attribute in each, `${a1#*;}` and `${a2#*;}` are used.

If no `';'` is contained in `$a1`, the attributes are printed unchanged. `IFS=,` insures the parameters are word-split on `','`.

(**note:** you should add validation that the filename is valid, etc. to your final script. You can also use `echo` if you like)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ splitattrib.sh file
Pos,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
1,a,b,-
2,c,e,+
2,d,f,+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your multiple entries are separated with semicolon `;`, here is the awk version to do.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[,]"
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /^[0-9].*/) {
        end_split_field = 0
        for (f=2;f<=NF;f++) {
            if ($f ~ /.*;.*/) {
                end_split_field=f
            }
        }

        if (end_split_field == 0) {
            print $0
        } else {
            for (f=2;f<=end_split_field;f++) {
                n = split($f, a, ";") #split and return the number
                for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                    b[f, i] = a[i]
                }
            }

            for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                printf $1","
                for (j=2;j<=end_split_field;j++) {
                    printf b[j, i]","
                }
                for (k=end_split_field;k<NF;k++) {
                    printf $k","
                }
                printf $NF"\n"
            }
        }
    } else {
        print $0
    }
}
```

Save the content above as `input.awk`, example input and output

```
$ cat input
Pos,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
1,a,b,-
2,c;d,e;f,+
3,g;h;i,j;k;l,-
```

---

We can get the split output

```
$ awk -f input.awk input
Pos,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
1,a,b,-
2,c,e,+
2,d,f,+
3,g,j,-
3,h,k,-
3,i,l,-
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! This seems to split the lines, but in my real data, only the first entry for each attribute is printed in a new line, ie:  
  
Pos,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3  
1,a,b,-  
2,c,e,+  
3,g,j,-

Comment: Could you provide a segment of your real data? it might be the reason of the format.

Comment: Hi Alijandro, thanks again! I've edited my question with more representative data.

Answer (score 0):

the best is break it to three part.

You have 3 line patterns. One has 6 columns. Another has 12, and the last  is 9.

6 columns => 1 line
12 columns => 3 lines
9 columns => 2 line

Your 6 columns should not be modified. So reminds 12, and 9. That you can separate them in the `if`, `else if` and `else`. Like:

```
if( column == 6 ){...}  
else if( column == 12 ){...}  
else {...}
```

And here is a **Perl one-liner** solution:

```
perl -a -F",|;" -lne '$s=scalar @F;if($s==6){print join ",",@F}elsif($s==12){print join",",@F[0,1,4,7,-2,-1];print join",",@F[0,1,5,8,-2,-1];print join",",@F[0,1,6,9,-2,-1];}else{print join",",@F[0,1,3,5,-2,-1];print join",",@F[0,1,4,6,-2,-1]} ' file
```

and for you input, the output is:

```
 1,ENST7,ENSP93,1,ENSG92,Gene1
 2,ENST25,ENSP91,515,ENSG765,Gene2
 2,ENST25,ENSP77,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 2,ENST25,ENSP78,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST25,ENSP91,515,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST25,ENSP77,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 3,ENST25,ENSP78,544,ENSG765,Gene2
 4,ENST54,ENSP83,1864,ENSG48,Gene3
 4,ENST54,ENSP36,722,ENSG48,Gene3
 5,ENST54,ENSP83,1864,ENSG48,Gene3
 5,ENST54,ENSP36,722,ENSG48,Gene3
 6,ENST54,ENSP83,1864,ENSG48,Gene3
 6,ENST54,ENSP36,722,ENSG48,Gene3
```